# Install Packages on Docker Official Wordpress Image

Tags: wordpress, docker, alpine-linux

I'm using the Docker Official Wordpress Image, which is based on Alpine. I need to install an editor in the image so that I can easily edit config files in the image. The Alpine that is used in this image seems not to have an editor or even the ask package manager. So, two questions:

1. How can I install apk?
2. Is there an editor in this image that I just can't find?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add vim into your Dockerfile.

create Dockerfile

```
wordpress:<version>-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache vim
```

do not forget to rebuild the Docker image

```
docker build -t wordpress .
```

Comment: Thank you. That would be a great solution, except, as far as I can tell, the wordpress alpine image has APK removed.

Comment: can you share a base image tag?